# Can't see any entries on "File Types" tab on Windows 7's Desktop Search

Tags: windows-7, windows-search, desktop-search

For some reason, Windows Desktop Search (included with Windows 7.0) now no longer shows any file types on the "Advanced Options" dialog box. Any ideas on how to fix this? WDS claims to be indexing...but I'm not sure what it's actually indexing right now.

[image]

I should also add that when I try to add a file type, nothing shows up or is ever actually added. If I login as a different user on the same system, everything appears normally.

Comment: Logging in with a local account fixed this for me.  More here: http://superuser.com/questions/385286/windows-search-index-options-doesnt-display-file-types/520463#520463

Comment: Is logging in with a different account a fix? For the domain user I was working with, **he** needed to search with **his** domain account. I was able to see the list logging on with a different account (a domain account, no less), but that didn't magically fix it for my user. Re-creating his profile fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by deleting and re-creating my Windows profile.

Comment: Fixed it for me, also. +1