# Windows Search Index options doesn't display file types

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

I'm running Windows 7 x64.  I was looking to add PDF indexing to Windows search and found that  when I look at Control Panel, Indexing Options, Advanced, File Types - the file types listing is empty.  The condition is referenced in this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/167310/cant-see-any-entries-on-file-types-tab-on-windows-7s-desktop-search), but the solution seems a bit draconian.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: FYI - I upgraded to Windows 8.1 recently and the same issue exists. The same solution works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a PC joined to a domain.  The behavior described above happens when I am logged in as a domain user (even onoe with local admin privileged. I found that if I login with a local account I am able to see and manage the indexed file types.

Comment: That's really not a fix if you are trying to make searching work for the domain account.

Comment: Perhaps not, but it is the only answer that seems to work for domain PCs. Are you aware of another fix?

Comment: Yes, re-creating the user profile fixes it. It's not an ideal fix but it does make indexing work again. The asker in this case links to an answer with that fix in their question. I'm surprised the administrator of your domain even allows you to log on with a local account.

Comment: unless, of course, I am one of the administrators... :-/

Answer (score 0):

I installed Adobe  PDF iFilter and it seems to work.

http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4025

Comment: It did the file types listing repopulate?

Comment: Already installed SO I reinstalled it to no avail.  THanks, tho